# Visual Studio for Mac strips the Bundle Display Name from Info.plist (CFBundleDisplayName)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I have a Xamarin.iOS project utilizing both the `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName` attributes in `Info.plist`.

When I open my project in the Visual Studio for Mac and then open the `Info.plist`, the `CFBundleDisplayName` attribute gets stripped off without a warrant. I can successfully edit the `Info.plist` in `Source` mode to append it back but is there a better way to overcome this problem?

Comment: @ColeXia Sorry, I don't really understand your answer. How do I avoid the stripping of `CFBundleDisplayName` every time I need to open the Info.plist in VS for Mac?

Comment: Did you forget to save it after editing ? It works fine on my side.

Comment: @ColeXia What works fine? Did you bother reading my question?

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with VS Mac 7.3.2. The CFBundleDisplayName attribute is not removed on opening or modifying the Info.plist using VS Mac. Can you provide more information or more detailed reproduction steps?

Comment: @MattWard Cannot reproduce the problem with the latest version of VS Mac (7.3.2) myself. The only remaining kind of a problem is that in 7.3.2 in source mode the attribute sort order looks rather chaotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Mac version 7.3.2 the problem does not reproduce.